# Low quality audio in headset when microphone is activated

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-headset

Anytime anything activates the mic (Discord, Skype, Webex, the recording tab in the sound part of the control panel) the audio quality in my headset is very low quality.

**To Reproduce:**

1. Play music of choice
2. Press the windows key and type sound
3. Click the Recording tab. Music will change to low quality
4. Click the Playback tab your music should sound normal
5. Rip hair out in frustration

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now on Ubuntu, is your headset USB? I think it may be line interference and therefore a hardware issue if our problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bluetooth it is expected behavior. BT bandwidth is not enough for good quality for two-way data transfer.
In my case I've faced awefull sound quality for JBL headset only. Other headsets work much better.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your answer? What source material or reference do you have that the bluetooth bandwidth isn't enough for good quality of transmit and receive? Which JBL headset did you have issues with? What other headsets did you find that worked?

Comment: I've found a bunch of articles about it (for example, this one https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/ ). My JBL Headset was Tune 700BT. With JBL it was unacceptable while other headsets works much better (AirPods, Nillkin Liberty, Anker Soundcore Life 2). But still any headset gets worse quality when Hands-Free mode is activated which means mic is turned on. And you could check properties in the windows playback deivces for both: Stereo and Hands-free to mark the difference in supported formats.